# How to get the ID of a newly created Firestore document in Vue.js?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

Using Vue.js and Firebase I am build the simplest CRUD I can think of.

When I 'create' data from a form I can send it to the database but when I try to update my local array of objects there is no document id, as this is created by firebase when I create a new document. So how can I retrieve the new document id without having to get all the data from the database?

There must be a pattern for this. The only thing I can think of doing is getting ***'all'*** the data from the database again. But is there an easier way?

Is there a way to get the id passed back to the component of a newly created document?

Here is my component with only the necessary bits,

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="crud">
    <h1>I am the crud component</h1>
    <div v-for="item in peoples" :key="peoples.id" class="peoples">
      <h3>name: {{ item.name}} age: {{ item.age}} id: {{ item.id }} <button @click="deletePeople(item.id)">delete</button> </h3>
    </div>
    <form @submit.prevent="addPerson()">
      <div>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" v-model="name">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="age">Age:</label>
        <input type="number" name="age" v-model="age">
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>add person to database</button>
      </div>
   </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import db from '@/firebase/init'

export default {
  name: 'Crud',
  data(){
    return {
      msg: 'hello all',
      peoples: [],
      name: null,
      age: null
    }
  },
  methods:{
    addPerson(){
      console.log('addPerson() method running');
      console.log('person: ' + this.name);
      db.collection('people').add({
        name: this.name,
        age: this.age
      }).then(() => {

        db.collection('people').get().then(snapshot => {
          this.peoples = []
          snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            // console.log(doc.data(), doc.id);
            let people = doc.data()
            people.id = doc.id
            this.peoples.push(people)
          })
        })

        // console.log('push to local data');
        // this.peoples.push({ name: this.name, age: this.age})
      })
    },
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ```
> // Add a new document with a generated id.
> db.collection("cities").add({
>     name: "Tokyo",
>     country: "Japan"
> })
> .then(function(docRef) {
>     console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
> })
> .catch(function(error) {
>     console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
> });
> ```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Here you could simply say `this.lastID = docRef.id` in the `.then()` and after that you can simply read out the document with the ID `lastID`.